# Python3 - error -NameError: name 'cy' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

This is a litle piece of code taht I am developing, and I have this error all time.. please Im really locked up, could anyone help me.. thank you in advice.
When I try the code I have this error message:
**NameError: name 'cy' is not defined**

```
   if contornos:
        for c in contornos:
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            area = w*y/2

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 
LINE_THICKNESS)                    

            if area >20:               
                m=cv2.moments(c)            
                cx=int(m['m10']/m['m00'])
                cy=int(m['m01']/m['m00'])                 
                cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),2,(0,0,255),5)

    if (conteo(cy,220)):
        contadorCoches +=1
```

Comment: This is not an issue with OpenCV.

Comment: @Lewis What will be the value of `cy` in the case when none of the contours have area > 20?

Comment: I think that all contours have area > 20 always... in my videos.. but it was for try to solve the error :( could you help me with that? @DanMašek

Answer (score 1):

There are times when the block of code in that if statement is not executing. You need to have meaningful values for those variables when area is not greater than 20.

Also do you mean for that last if statement to only check the final value of cy? Right now it will only be applied to the last value cy attains at the end of the for loop.